# How To Append Data in Bulk Insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to read chunks of data saved in my data table.Using the query Below i save this answer in a datatable 3 and then use the buk insert TO Table_1.

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DistrictName) AS Row, *FROM Dwh_staging_table) AS a WHERE row BETWEEN 0 AND 1000001", con1);
```

This is the SQL statement on its own:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DistrictName) AS Row, *
     FROM Dwh_staging_table
    ) AS a
WHERE row BETWEEN 0 AND 1000001
```

How would i append the Row's after 1000001 in the Table_1.

Comment: Do you need to read chunks and after processing 100000 records you want to add next row to data table or you need next set of rows and continue your operation

Comment: i will access the rows after the 100000 and save it in a data table and append these rows in the same table.....

Comment: so you are reading from some table in Database and after some operations you are inserting in the same table stored in database?

Comment: No after reading all the rows in a table named table_1 from 0 -100000 i just used bulk insert ...then again i read rows after 100001 - 200000 and so on i just want to append these 100001 - 200000 after the 100000th row in the table_1   ( I am reading these rows from another table)

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding you correctly, are you trying to copy all rows from Table A to Table B using C#, with a batch size of 100000 rows?

Comment: yes and after selecting every 100000 rows i run the insert bulk and son on after the another 100000

Answer (score 0):

We use `select` query with `Limit` in `SQLITE`

> SELECT * from [table-name] Limit LowerBound, UpperBound

So you query will be something like,

```
SELECT * FROM Dwh_staging_table ORDER BY DistrictName Limit 0, 100000
```

For the next block,

```
SELECT * FROM Dwh_staging_table ORDER BY DistrictName Limit 100000, 200000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good post on how to do paging in TSql

http://joelabrahamsson.com/my-favorite-way-to-do-paging-with-t-sql/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

The following code will efficiently copy data from the SourceTableName@SourceConnectionString, to the DestinationTableName@DestinationConnectionString, 100000 rows at a time. Obviously replace the tokens with your connection strings and table names.

```
using (var sourceConnection = new SqlConnection("[SourceConnectionString]"))
using (var destinationConnection = new SqlConnection("[DestinationConnectionString]"))
{
    sourceConnection.Open();
    destinationConnection.Open();

    var sourceCommand = sourceConnection.CreateCommand();
    sourceCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sourceCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [SourceTableName]";
    var sourceReader = sourceCommand.ExecuteReader();

    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection)
    {
        DestinationTableName = "[DestinationTableName]",
        BatchSize = 100000
    };

    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceReader);
}
```